# Will windows XP 32-Bit OS read 8GB of RAM?

Tags: windows, operating-system, ram

Am using Windows XP 32-Bit Operating System with Intel Xeon processor. My current RAM memory is 4GB and 320GB of hard disk. And I feel that my computer is very slow. So if I upgrade the RAM memory to 8GB, will my computer handle the upgrade?

Comment: Here is stackoverflow, which is Q&A site about programming. Visit [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: And not - 32-bit operating system can use 4GB (or less) at most

Answer (score 0):

I probably do not think so. 32 bit OS can only support 4 GB of memory.

Calculation example:

2 ^ 32 bytes = 4 GB.

If you want more than 4 gb to use, then use a 64 bit OS

Answer (score 0):

No,friend your computer will not use 8GB ram. At first you will have to know what is ram,
ram is a device that store information for temporarily, and share that data with very speedy and less consuming time.In 32 bit OS ram can hold data of 2 ^ 32 bytes = 4 GB if u have 8 gb ram, you 32 bit system can not use it,
Think about a car garage which is constructed for 4 cars, if you have 10 car you can't put all of your in the garage, so your 32 bit OS can not hold information more than 4gb ram, like car garage.Hope it will help you to get your answer

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it could: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension, but in XP there is no support for this.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your os to 64 bit to use 8gb ram.
Just wondering, why did you put windows xp 32 bit on your computer? it could be x64 edition. Intel xeon processors are 64 BIT, not 32 bit.